# a little problem about Rolle theorem

Tags: rolles-theorem, legendre-functions

As Rolle theorem goes,if

1. $f(x)$ is continuous and well-defined in $[a,b]$,
2. derivable in $(a,b)$, and $f'(x)$ is bounded,
3. $f(a)=f(b)$,

then there exists $c$ ($a<c<b$), which satisfies $f'(c)=0$.

I wonder how to find how many $c$'s there are in a given interval like $[a,b]$? *e.g.* while seeking the number of roots of Legendre multinomial, although $x=1$ and $x=-1$ are two null points, we can't say there only exits one $c$ ($f'(c)=0$).

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Obviously we'll need more information because obviously one can immediately construct an example with $n$ zeros, for any given $n$. Or infinitely many.

Comment: By the way, I have never seen the condition "$f'(x)$ is bounded", and think it is redundant.

Comment: I'm sorry for my unclear expression, in fact  i wanna ask the question about the process of proof of the number of roots of Legendre multinomial.

Answer (score 1):

Rolle's theorem is what mathematicians call an "existence proof", which proves that something exists without actually telling you how to calculate it. The opposite of that is (according to Wikipedia) a "constructive proof" or an "effective proof".

Solving for $f'(x)=0$ is described as finding the *critical points* of the function $f$. Critical points may be either local minima, local maxima, or points like the one at $x=0$ for $f(x)=x^3$ where the graph is just parallel with the $x$ axis. We have to also compute $f''(x)$ to work out which one.

Rolle's theorem just tells you that a critical point (in fact a maximum or a minimum, since $f(a)=f(b)$) must exist, without telling you how to calculate it. There is no general way to tell how many exist. For example for the case that $f(x)=C$, where $C$ is a constant, it's clear that $f'(x)=0$ for all values of $x\in [a,b]$.